# Mobile automation using Appium and Selenium for Android

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

In mobile automation using **Appium** and **Selenium WebDriver** for Android mobile, what is the difference between  `capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2")` and  `capabilities.setCapability("version", "4.2")`?

Answer (score 0):

both are same. CapatilityType.VERSION returns a constant which is version.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/constant-values.html#org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.VERSION

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both are exactly same. `CapabilityType.VERSION` returns the version as a string constant. But as a practice we are using `CapabilityType.VERSION` for `"version"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same in first we are using "Version" library and in second e